XML parsing in Snowflake
So I have an XML document that has been loaded from a stage into a variant column in Snowflake looks like this.
<LIST_OUTPUT>
    <RESPONSE>
        <EMP_LIST>
            <EMP>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <TYPE>PERMANENT</TYPE>
                <DOC_LIST>
                    <DOC>
                        <ID>DOC-001</ID>
                        <TYPE>PASSPORT</TYPE>
                    </DOC>
                    <DOC>
                        <ID>DOC-002</ID>
                        <TYPE>DRIVING LICENSE</TYPE>
                    </DOC>
                </DOC_LIST>
            </EMP>
            <EMP>
                <ID>2</ID>
                <TYPE>CONTRACTOR</TYPE>
                <DOC_LIST>
                    <DOC>
                        <ID>DOC-001</ID>
                        <TYPE>PASSPORT</TYPE>
                    </DOC>
                    <DOC>
                        <ID>DOC-002</ID>
                        <TYPE>DRIVING LICENSE</TYPE>
                    </DOC>
                </DOC_LIST>
            </EMP>
        </EMP_LIST>
    </RESPONSE>
</LIST_OUTPUT>

I am trying to put it into an employees table so it looks like



emp_id
emp_type
emp_docs




1
PERMANENT
[PASSPORT,DRIVING LICENCE]


2
CONTRACTOR
[PASSPORT,DRIVING LICENCE]



So far I have
select xmlget(emp.value,'ID'):"$" AS EMP_ID
       ,XMLGET(emp.value,'TYPE'):"$" AS EMP_TYPE
from raw_xml
, lateral flatten(xmlget(xmlget(xml,'RESPONSE'),'EMP_LIST'):"$") emp

but not sure how to pull the docs type into one column. any pointers?

        select distinct  XMLGET(EMP_LIST.VALUE,'ID'):"$" :: INTEGER as EMP_ID 
,xmlget(EMP_LIST.value,'TYPE'):"$" :: string as EMP_TYPE
        
        ,array_agg( xmlget(doc.value,'TYPE'):"$"::STRING) within group(order by xmlget(doc.value,'ID'):"$" :: STRING ) over (partition by XMLGET(EMP_LIST.VALUE,'ID') ) as emp_docs_array
        
     ,listagg( xmlget(doc.value,'TYPE'):"$"::STRING,',') within group (order by xmlget(doc.value,'ID'):"$" :: STRING) over (partition by XMLGET(EMP_LIST.VALUE,'ID') )  as emp_docs_list
        
    from raw_xml
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET(xmlget(xml,'RESPONSE'),'EMP_LIST'):"$") AS EMP_LIST 
    ,LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET(EMP_LIST.VALUE,'DOC_LIST'):"$") as doc

Output:



select xmlget(emp.value,'ID'):"$" AS EMP_ID
       ,xmlget(emp.value,'TYPE'):"$" AS EMP_TYPE
       ,array_agg(xmlget(doc.value,'TYPE'):"$") as EMP_DOCS
from raw_xml
, lateral flatten(xmlget(xmlget(xml,'RESPONSE'),'EMP_LIST'):"$") emp
, lateral flatten(toarray(xmlget(emp.value,'DOC_LIST'):"$")) doc
GROUP BY 1,2

Managed to get it working with the above.
Vaniuser22 worked all good, until there was only one document in doc_list and it would pull through nulls.
helped with this answer provided here
